# How to make image randomly appear on screen

Tags: java, android, imageview

I want my ImageView Randomly appear on my android screen position, because I'm creating a Whack-A-Mole game, and I want those to be clickable. How do I do it? Am I gonna use OnTouchEvents?

Comment: I guess this is what you need https://github.com/Mquinn960/mole-app

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `FrameLayout` then set the height and width to `match_parent` then get the screen width and height.  Once you have those you can subtract the size of your image (so it doesn't go off screen) then generate a random number between 0 and height and 0 and width.  Once you have the location you can create a new `ImageView` programmatically then set it's position with `setX(...)` and `setY(...)` set an `onClickListener` and add it to the `FrameLayout`.  When it is clicked you can remove it and repeat the whole process.

Comment: May I know why am I using FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout

Comment: RelativeLayout would work as well, but you aren't using the relative part so FrameLayout is just less overhead and will be faster since relative layouts make 2 passes

Answer (score 0):

```
 final TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image);
    final Random rand = new Random();
    final int rndInt = rand.nextInt(imgs.length());
    final int resID = imgs.getResourceId(rndInt, 0);
    imageviewplace = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageviewplace);
    imageviewplace.setImageResource(resID);
    imageviewplace.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Comment: Random image from drawable will be shown  (R.array.image)  every refresh or load activity  random image load in imageview